# C++ sin() function sometimes returns different values for the same argument

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, trigonometry

Sometimes sin function in C++ returns slightly different values (in 8th decimal position).
What can be the reason?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <immintrin.h>


std::ofstream toFile("file.txt");
double xValue = 1.3808129283228576;

void func(int nValues) {
    std::vector<double> results(nValues);
    for (int i=0; i<nValues; i++) {
        results[i] = sin(xValue);
        uint64_t *ptrX     = (uint64_t *)&xValue;
        uint64_t *ptrValue = (uint64_t *)&results[i];
        toFile << xValue << " " << results[i] << "   " << std::hex << *ptrX << " " << *ptrValue << " " << 
                  _mm_getcsr() << "\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(30));
    }
    for (int i=0; i+1<nValues; i++)
        if (fabs(results[i] - results[i+1]) > 1e-10) {
            toFile << "ERROR:\n" << results[i] << "\n" << results[i+1] << "\n";
            std::cout <<  "ERROR:\n" << results[i] << "\n" << results[i+1] << "\n";
            return;
        }
    toFile << "OK\n";
    std::cout << "OK\n";
}

int main() {
    toFile.   precision(16);
    std::cout.precision(16);
    func(1000);
    return 0;
}
```

The values in file.txt are, e.g.:

```
1.380812928322858 0.9820073703281703   3ff617cf4c10a691 3fef6c9ab87fb1c9 1fa0
1.380812928322858 0.9820073703281703   3ff617cf4c10a691 3fef6c9ab87fb1c9 1fa0
1.380812928322858 0.9820073703281703   3ff617cf4c10a691 3fef6c9ab87fb1c9 1fa0
1.380812928322858 0.982007359072273    3ff617cf4c10a691 3fef6c9ab274b21b 1fa0
1.380812928322858 0.982007359072273    3ff617cf4c10a691 3fef6c9ab274b21b 1fa0
1.380812928322858 0.982007359072273    3ff617cf4c10a691 3fef6c9ab274b21b 1fa0
1.380812928322858 0.9820073703281703   3ff617cf4c10a691 3fef6c9ab87fb1c9 1fa0
1.380812928322858 0.9820073703281703   3ff617cf4c10a691 3fef6c9ab87fb1c9 1fa0
1.380812928322858 0.9820073703281703   3ff617cf4c10a691 3fef6c9ab87fb1c9 1fa0
```

Compiler: g++ 9.2 as well as 11.2 from Mingw (Windows), flags: -O3

Update: added output of the hex-representation of xValue and sin(xValue).

Update: added result of the _mm_getcsr() function.

Comment: Try use newer version of g++. Here you can [download](https://winlibs.com) some. Because I cannot reproduce this(I use g++11.3)

Comment: Does -O3 include the fast-math flag?

Comment: Cosmic rays? That's a big difference. I'm not sure but I don't think there should be any difference at all.

Comment: @Brannon No. But I don't think this would be a fastmath thing anyway... that wouldn't lead to inconsistencies like this. (If anything, it would remove them.)

Comment: My best guess is that some injected thread is playing fast and loose with the FP control word. Ordinarily I'd suspect D3D, but with the program apparently not doing any multimedia stuff, I can't think what it would be.....

Comment: @Deumaudit: The same problem also appears for g++ 11.2.

Comment: It shouldn't affect your issue, but you should use `std::sin` and `std::fabs`, as `<cmath>` is not guaranteed to provide these in the global namespace.

Comment: @bcsb1001: The same problem also with std::sin :(

Comment: You should write the binary/hex representation of the float to the file - that way you can see if its `sin` or the formatted outputting which is giving you inconsistencies. (e.g. in addition just memcpy the float to an int, and output the int).

Comment: @MikeVine: I have added the mentioned output for the double-values: xValue is really the same, sin() changes sometimes.

Comment: ok thats good. The next step (assuming you are on x64) is to print out the MXCSR in each iteration. You can get this via `https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=getcsr&ig_expand=3680`. This will show you if the floating point flags change at all. Just `#include <immintrin.h>` and call `int reg = _mm_getcsr();`

Comment: @MikeVine I have added result of the _mm_getcsr() to the output. This value seems to be unchanged: 1fa0

Comment: The std::sin() function should only be used with tiny angles, so keep that in mind. Because of the constraints of the approximation techniques and the precision of the floating-point type, the function may yield erroneous answers for bigger angles. If so, you might need to calculate an angle's sine using a different approach.

Comment: @Gandalf Period of sine function is 2*pi~6,28. So I would not expect the value 1,38 to be extremely large :)

Comment: @BorysL. These algorithms are not always exact, and they may produce slightly different results depending on the specific implementation of the function.

Comment: @Gandalf the issue is inconsistency, nothing to do with imprecision in the implementation.

Comment: I dont know how to proceeed there. Looking at the generated assembly there's nothing ib this program (as expected) which could cause this weirdness. You'd have to look into/disssassemble the `sin` function from your stdlib.